# Create CDA document with data available

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, hl7, cda

I am working on a health care application which has a user's health care data. I need help to export this data into a CDA document using Rails or Javascript

Answer (score 1):

CDA is just XML. Use your favourite library (JAXB should be available via Groovy/Java) to feed your data (from a DB?) to your CDA. Get the CDA schemas and try to generate the classes you need.
Another approach: use a templating engine (velocity or the like).

Start with a sample CDA and from there try to understand the intricacies of CDA.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could work.

```
require 'builder'
@schools = School.where(state_code: 'NV').order('name DESC')
file = File.new("#{Rails.root}/public/data.xml", 'w')

xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(target: file, :indent => 2)
xml.instruct! :xml, :version=>'1.0'

xml.tag! 'plist' , 'version' => '1.0' do
  xml.array do
    @schools.each do |s|
      xml.dict do
        xml.key 'id'
        xml.string s.id
        xml.key 'name'
        xml.string s.name
        xml.key 'zip'
        xml.string s.zipcode
      end
    end
  end
end
```